# ASP.NET javascript code is not working while putting an element's runat="server"

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

my `html` and `javascript` code is working correctly. But while I put it in `asp.net`, the `javascript` code isn't working.

My `html` code is...

```
 <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-3 col-xs-12 control-label">Work Completed</label>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">  
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon">%</span>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="" id="tval" oninput="changeDiv()" runat="server"/>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-3 col-xs-12 control-label"></label>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">                                                                                                                                        
            <div class="progress progress-thick progress-striped active">
                <div id="p_bar" class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" role="progressbar" ></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

and the `javascript` code is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function changeDiv() {
        tval = document.getElementById('tval').value;
        document.getElementById('p_bar').setAttribute("style", "width:" + tval + "%");
    }
</script>
```

This works perfectly. The code above is to change the `progressbar` `(id="p_bar")` value with textbox  `(id="tval")` input and the `progressbar` range increases or decreases with the value.

But when I put `runat="server"` in `<input type="text">`, the code is not working.

I am unable to find the solution.

Please help me.

Comment: also add this `ClientIDMode="Static"`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By  using `ClientIDMode="Static"` in your server control it will not change `ID` of that element on Page Render & hence your existing javascript/jquery will work.

So Replace this:-

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="" id="tval" oninput="changeDiv()" runat="server"/>
```

with

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="" id="tval" oninput="changeDiv()" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"/>
```

or

if you don't want to use `ClientIDMode="Static"`

please replace your ID wherever you used `runat="server"`, like this:-

`tval = document.getElementById('<%=tval.ClientID%>').value;`

Answer (score 2):

you have to add ClientID when you create your textbox as server control.

so try this,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function changeDiv() {
        tval = document.getElementById('<%=tval.ClientID%>').value;
        document.getElementById('p_bar').setAttribute("style", "width:" + tval + "%");
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

As input tag is a html tag (markup language) you cannot use an asp.net  *runat* attribute,instead you can use

Example:`<asp:Label runat="server">` if it is suitable.

Comment: Yes, you can. ASP.NET will transform it into a HTML control. The web controls are another thing.

Answer (score 0):

Try to call it with class name instead of id if you need to use `runat="server"`.
Such as:

```
$('.classname').val();
```

**or** :

```
document.getElementsByClassName("classname");
```